# Flexible database models for users to define extra columns to database tables in Django

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I am trying to build a tool that, at a simple level, tries to analyse how to buy a flat. DB = POSTGRES

So the model basically is:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    address = CharField(max_length = 200)   
    price = IntegerField()
    user = ForeignKey(User)     # user who entered the property in the database
    #..
    #..
    # some more fields that are common across all flats



    #However, users might have their own way of analysing 

    # one user might want to put

    estimated_price = IntegerField() # his own estimate of the price, different from the zoopla or rightmove listing price
    time_to_purchase = IntegerField()  # his own estimate on how long it will take to purchase


    # another user might want to put other fields
    # might be his purchase process requires sorting or filtering based on these two fields

    number_of_bedrooms = IntegerField()
    previous_owner_name = CharField()
```

How do I give such flexiblity to users? They should be able to sort , filter and query their own rows (in the Property table) by these custom fields. The only option I can think of now is the JSONField Postgres field

Any advice? I am surprised this is not solved readily in Django - I am sure lots of other people would have come across this problem already

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Edit: As the comments point out. JSON field is a better idea in this case.

Simple. Use Relations.

Create a model called attributes.

It will have a foreign key to a Property, a name field and a value field.

Something like,

```
class Attribute(models.Model):
    property = models.ForiegnKey(Property)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

Create an object each for all custom attributes of a property.

When using database queries use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) of [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) for faster response, less db operations.

Comment: This is known as Entity Attribute Value, or EAV modelling. Using a JSONField is a better option than this, you can index columns of a JSONField if they become popular.

Comment: We've done a few EAV implementations with relations. It works, it scales, but when it gets really big it tends to get overwhelming. We've started working on a JSON solution: https://github.com/zostera/django-jeaves